# Meaning of "À moins qu'il n'en eût soixante"

Tags: grammaire

Context:

> Ursus avait cinquante ans, à moins qu'il n'en eût soixante.

My interpretation:
Ursus had 50 years, unless that him didn't have sixty.

Which don't make any sense.

Comment: This is a sentence from *L'homme qui rit* by Victor Hugo, I expect that if you read this book you are not a beginner in French and you could use a dictionary. You cannot get the second part of the sentence right because you did not understand the first part. Look up [*il avait cinquante ans*](http://www.reverso.net/translationresults.aspx?lang=FR&direction=francais-anglais) in a dictionary.  Then look up for  [*il*](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/il) , which cannot be "him", it is a subject pronoun.

Comment: [This](https://www.frenchlearner.com/phrases/how-old-are-you/) might help you as well.

Comment: Once you have mastered the first part of the sentence, what is it precisely you do not understand ? you got *à moins que* right, so I expect it must be *en*, which indeed is a little tricky.  Here *en* is a personal pronoun standing for *ans*, you will find lots of posts on *en* on this site, if you can't find any that help you, I suggest you rephrase your question to be more explicit about the precise word you do not understand.

Comment: @Laure I think the "tricky" bit is the *n'*, which is not present in most other languages. Changing *didn't have* for *had* would make "sense" in the broken English version.

Comment: @rsanchez "...Unless that him had sixty" doesn't make sense either. It seems there's a lot more OP doesn't understand. We are here to help and explain if they are a little more precise.

Comment: *À moins que* translates to *unless*, so you have an extra *that* in your translation. And *en* would translate to *of them* here.  So literally: *Ursus had 50 years, unless he had 60 of them.* More idiomatically, *Ursus was 50, if he wasn't 60*.

Comment: The exact quote is "Ursus avait cinquante ans, à moins qu'il n'en eût soixante."

Comment: Is it the “ne” that bothers you in this sentence?

Comment: Ah @Laure you're back! You were gone from the site for so long. (I'm Aerovistae, just slightly anonymized.)

Comment: @temporary_user_name Hi!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You made a few mistakes in your translation:

> Ursus had 50 years, unless that him didn't have sixty.

1. You translated *il* as "him". But *il* is a subject pronoun, so you must translate it as "he":

> Ursus had 50 years, unless that **he** didn't have sixty.

2. The Romantic idiom uses *avoir* for your age, while the Germanic idiom uses *to be*. Luckily, the translations between them are more or less seamless. (On the same note, in English you say either "to be *n*" or "to be *n* years old".)

> Ursus **was** 50 years **old**, unless that he **wasn't** sixty.

3. When you encounter *ne* in French and it isn't paired with a negative particle (*pas*, *rien*, *jamais*, *aucun*, *que*, etc.), it's almost always semantically empty, rather than indicating verbal negation.

> Ursus was 50 years old, unless that he **was** sixty.

4. You translated a grammatically correct French phase (*à moins que* + clause) by a grammatically incorrect English prase (*unless that* + clause). When translating, you should avoid word-for-word substitution, at the very least whenever it leads to broken grammar.

> Ursus was 50 years old, **unless** he was sixty.

This is now a "literal" translation, and has yielded an English sentence whose meaning is unambiguous. Getting here is the first step. Next, we need to ensure that it's natural and fits in context. That means asking, ["What is the speaker trying to say?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_and_formal_equivalence) Sometimes you're lucky and the literal translation has the same force in both languages. But often, you have to adjust in the target language to make sure that readers understand what the author meant them to understand.

In this case, I would probably go with something like this, with the caveat that I would need to read the sentence in the original paragraph to be sure.

> **Ursus was fifty years old — though he might well have been sixty.**

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the sentence quoted, the author expresses a certain hesitation regarding the age of Ursus. He’s not really sure of Ursus' exact age.

In the second part of the sentence, the author goes back on this statement by saying `à moins que` to designate his previously quoted statement.

Literally, I think you can translate `à moins que` with `Unless`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the context but it means that the narrator thinks that Ursus was 50 years old but he could be 60 years old. Their main opinion is 50 but they have a doubt of him being older.

Comment: The translation into English would be "Ursus was fifty, unless he was
sixty." But giving a translation doesn't help much where future reference is concerned...